# Bot Framework composer -Luis build failed:

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to build a Chatbot where I can use the Bot effectively with Luis.

I'm trying to follow the sample `TodoBotewithLuisSample` provided in the composer itself.

When I connect my Bot with Luis and try to publish I get the error below:

> "Luis build failed: The apps - Get applications list Operation under
> LUIS Programmatic APIs v3.0-preview is not supported with the current
> subscription key and pricing tier LUIS.F0."

Is that the under free pricing tier LUIS.F0, we cannot run BotFramework Composer?

Comment: You didn't find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: Any update please?

Comment: I think its well known but no fix available: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues/599

Answer (score 1):

As per reply in GitHub Issue :

Same issue got resolved for me.
Step 1 - Logged in luis portal
Step 2 - Selected the azure resources
Step 3 - Selected authorisation for the same
Step 4 - Copied the LUIS key from Luis website
Step 5 - Pasted in the Bot composer

It Worked for me.